# Where to store DocumentDB Endpoint and Key in production

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-cosmosdb

I have a .Net Core website and Xamarin app that talk to Documentdb and we are preparing to go to production.

All docs I have seen on DocumentDB / CosmosDB hard copy the Key and Endpoint in a C# class. Example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-develop-documentdb-dotnet , http://www.dotnetcurry.com/windows-azure/1395/cosmosdb-webapi-angular-client , to list a few (!), and Azure Security in DocumentDB does not seem to address or mention this issue.

Is there a way to securely store DocuementDB EndPoint and Key in client apps?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never use the keys in applications. Azure Key Vault solve this problem.

Please check this

https://sarosh.wordpress.com/2017/11/23/cosmos-db-and-key-vault/

HTH

Answer (score 0):

**KeyChain.Net**

A simple and unified api that enables developer to set, update, get and delete keys and passwords on the keyChain (supports iOS, Android, and WinPhone)

https://github.com/has-taiar/KeyChain.Net

**iOS**

```
var helper = new KeyChain.Net.XamarinIOS.KeyChainHelper();
var isSaved = helper.SetKey("myKey", "myKeyValue");
var keyValue = helper.GetKey("myKey");
var isDeleted = helper.DeleteKey("myKey");
```

**Android**

```
var helper = new KeyChain.Net.XamarinAndroid.KeyChainHelper(myActivity, "myKeyProtectionPassword");
var isSaved = helper.SetKey("myKey", "myKeyValue");
var keyValue = helper.GetKey("myKey");
var isDeleted = helper.DeleteKey("myKey");
```

**Windows Phone**

```
var helper = new KeyChain.Net.XamarinWinRT.KeyChainHelper();
var isSaved = helper.SetKey("myKey", "myKeyValue");
var keyValue = helper.GetKey("myKey");
var isDeleted = helper.DeleteKey("myKey");
```